# Combine neighbouring lines

Tags: regex

I need to combine this:

```
"1381733226.6811","Form1","your-email","example1@gmail.com","1",NULL
"1381733226.6811","Form1","your-subject","foo1","2",NULL
"1381733868.4487","Form1","your-email","example2@gmail.com","1",NULL
"1381733868.4487","Form1","your-subject","foo2","2",NULL
"1381734307.5494","Form1","your-email","example3@gmail.com","1",NULL
"1381734307.5494","Form1","your-subject","foo3","2",NULL
"1381735753.0189","Form1","your-email","example4@gmail.com","1",NULL
"1381735753.0189","Form1","your-subject","foo4","2",NULL
```

into this:

```
example1@gmail.com - foo1
example2@gmail.com - foo2
example3@gmail.com - foo3
example4@gmail.com - foo4
```

Some of lines are "bad" and they should be avoided. For example:

```
"1387658626.6811","Form1","your-email","example1@gmail.com","1",NULL
"1381124126.1211","Form1","your-subject","foo1","2",NULL
```

or:

```
"1381733226.6811","Form1","your-email","example1@gmail.com","1",NULL
"1381733226.6811","Form1","your-email","foo1","2",NULL
```

I already tried do change this:

```
"\d+?\.\d+?","Form1","your-email","([^\r\n])*","1",NULL\r?\n"\d+?\.\d+?","Form1","your-subject","([^\r\n])*","2",NULL)
```

to this:

```
$1 - $2
```

But I failed and its not working :/. Have you any ideas?

Comment: Programming language?

Answer (score -1):

You can use this regex, this is the correct form of your regex:

```
"(?<id>\d+?\.\d+?)","Form1","your-email","([^"]*)","1",NULL\r?\n"\k<id>","Form1","your-subject","([^"]*)","2",NULL
```

and replace with

```
$2 - $3
```

I modified the selection of content to `([^"]*)` to ensure that it will match only the right content, and passed the * inside the selection.

Modified the regex to verifi if the ID is the same in both lines. [working sample](https://regex101.com/r/W3X1Ks/1)